# Multivariable Calculus - Double Integration Problem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I've attempted this question twice, with both times giving me the incorrect answer. Could I please have a step by step method on how to solve this please? Thank-you very much.

Find the volume of the solid that lies under the plane 
$$4x + 10y − 2z + 19 = 0$$
 and above the rectangle 
$$R = \{(x, y) | −1 \leq x \leq 2, −1 \leq y \leq 1\}$$

Comment: Find te integral under the region $R$ of the function $z(x,y)=(1/2)(4x+10y+19)$.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: Yes, welcome to MSE, but it's much more productive if you post your attempted solution and we can explain to you what error you made. You'll learn far more that way.

Comment: @Andrei I got an answer of 60 which was incorrect, and an answer of 63 which was also incorrect. Did exactly what the two answers beneath this have done.

Comment: @TedShifrin ^ read my reply to Andrei

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{-1}^{2} \int_{-1}^{1} dx dy\int_0^{2x+5y+\frac{19}{2}} dz$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{2} \int_{-1}^{1} dx dy (2x+5y+\frac{19}{2})$$

$$=6+0+57=63$$.

Comment: I also entered 63 into webassign, and I was told the answer was incorrect.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B2%7D%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E1+%7B2x%2B5y%2B9.5%7D+dy+dx

Comment: Inform your instructor. Webassign may have been coded incorrectly.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank-God, I thought I was going crazy. Pretty sure I got it right with 63. Thanks anyway :S

Comment: It is correct and like always an other ...